# Maintain the new line of custom label while throwing custom exception

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have custom label `C_label` with the value `I am God. God is Great.`

```
C_label = I am God.
    God is Great.
```

The second sentence is in a new line.

When I use this custom label to show message in exception, the message is displayed in a single line.

```
try
{
   divide by 0;  //exception here causes to enter catch block
}
   catch(exception e);
{
   throw exception(Label.C_label);
}
```

The message is displayed as `I am God. God is Great.` . The second will not be displayed in a new line.
Is there any way to maintain the format ?

**Workaround i used:**

Split the string with any random character.

```
String s = 'I am God. 555 God is Great'.
List<String> l = s.split('555');
Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,''+l[0]));
Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,''+l[1]));
```

Display the message using `<apex:pageMessages>;`. The message will be displayed with bullets in a separate line.

Comment: Did you try to use pageMessages ? You have an attribut named "escape". If set to "false" you can add html tag in your custom label like <BR/> in order to display your message in two lines

Comment: user2294438, I've edited your post to remove the html tags and to format your code using the preformatted text button and inline escapes where I believed it appropriate. If I've misinterpreted your intent, please visit [Help] to learn how to use the editor so your messages will display correctly.